# Google Maps how to find nearest available driver

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directions-api

I am developing an iOS mobile application based on Google Map APIs.

Simply driver can select his **From** & **To** locations. Then using directions API app will show the shortest path. (App will save latitude and longitude on the server side)

Also, a passenger can select his **From** & **To** locations & app will save those latitude and longitude coordinates.

Can someone advise me how can I find the nearest available drivers when a passenger selects his **From** & **To** locations?

Comment: Look into using the Haversine formula.

Comment: Do you want to find the nearest marker with JS or PHP?

Comment: I need to find that in swift. If you have steps in PHP or JS please post here. I can convert that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using then go with geofire it has all necessary method built in to find nearest locations.https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc